# Adding HTML Button using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In an application that I am building, I need to display different kinds of buttons for users with different designations (HOD, Director or Staff).
Consider the code snippet-

```
        <button id="request">Leave Request</button>
        <button id="statistics">Leave Statistics</button>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT Role from employee where `Emp Code`=$emp_code";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        $row =mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
        if($row[0] == "HOD"){
            echo "<button id='new'> New Button</button>";
        }
```

So is the logged in used is a HOD then he/she should see 3 buttons.

Error displaying-  Couldn't fetch query. Parameter 1 in mysqli_fetch_array should be mysqli_result, none given.

Comment: your query failed and you need to find out why `$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: `$row =mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);` and you're checking for a string.

Comment: Is your empcode an integer or string?

Comment: @Fred-ii using  die(mysqli_error($link)); , it shows the same error explained above. Is it not the proper way to check for string? How should I check then?

Comment: @BartScheffer It's a string

Comment: Then you should use ' ' around the variabele

Comment: you have an answer below, I'd only stand in the way.

Comment: plus, code snippets isn't full code. So, I don't know what else I would be up against. Just do as Bart said, quote your variable; it's a string, not an integer. You may see magic happen ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As OP mentioned in comments the table structure is `emp_name, emp_code, password, emailID, role - varchar(50)` and `$emp_code` is string.

and the query OP is trying;

```
$sql = "SELECT Role from employee where `Emp Code`=$emp_code";
```

so query should be

```
$sql = "SELECT role FROM employee WHERE emp_code='$emp_code'";
```

Comment: even though I use "SELECT Role from employee where `Emp Code`='aal01' ". aal01 is a value in 'Emp Code' column , it is showing the same error

Comment: check the queries in answer, you have wrong table col names in query, if as you mentioned in comments that the table col is `emp_code` but in query you are trying with `Emp Code`

Comment: and same goes with col `role` and you are trying `Role`

Comment: there is no possible way the col name will be `Emp Code` can't put space between 2 words, so it's totally wrong

Comment: @Shehary Not quite ^ ^ Although not considered good practice, spaces are allowed but ticks are required to be used around table/column names. However, it looks like the OP's column name is different than what they originally used.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are right, actually i never saw and never tried to create a col having space between 2 words, always used `_` so i didn't know that it's possible and it can be done but just created a col with space between 2 words and yes I was Totally Wrong about my comment :)

Comment: @Shehary Same thing for a hyphen `table or col-name`, allowed, but not good practice and also requires ticks around it. MySQL sees that as wanting to do math. I.e.: "col **minus** name".

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah agree with you `-` hyphen is not practice also. space between 2 words in col name was something new to me, glad learned something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on my phone but since emp_code is a string please try the following. Notice the ' ' around $emp_code

```
        <button id="request">Leave Request</button>
    <button id="statistics">Leave Statistics</button>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT Role from employee where `Emp Code`='$emp_code'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $row =mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
    if($row[0] == "HOD"){
        echo "<button id='new'> New Button</button>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this .

```
        <button id="request">Leave Request</button>
        <button id="statistics">Leave Statistics</button>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT `role` from employee where `emp_code`='".$emp_code."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($sql);
        $row =mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
        if($row[0] == "HOD"){
            echo "<button id='new'> New Button</button>";
        }
```

Comment: Didn't work even now!

Comment: Please post `employee` table structure.

Comment: emp_name, emp_code, password, emailID, role - varchar(50)

Comment: Please check updated answer.. use emp_code instead of  Emp Code.Modified $sql query as per your table structure $sql = "SELECT `role` from employee where `emp_code`=$emp_code";